# Is it possible to pass string data from javascript to html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two files, "a.js" and "b.html". Is is possible to append the string data created from "a.js" to "b.html" head tag? This is the code where I assemble the string data from "a.js" file.

a.js:

```
createChart: function () {
    var pieChartScript1 =
      '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>' +
      '<script type="text/javascript">' +
      'google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});' +
      'google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);' +
      'function drawChart() {' +
      'var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([';

    var pieChartScript2 = '[' + '0~999' + ',  ' + one.length + '],';
    pieChartScript2 += '[' + '1000~1999' + ',  ' + two.length + '],';
    pieChartScript2 += '[' + '2000~2999' + ',  ' + three.length + '],';
    pieChartScript2 += '[' + '3000~3999' + ',  ' + four.length + '],';
    pieChartScript2 += '[' + '4000~4999' + ',  ' + five.length + '],';
    pieChartScript2 += '[' + '5000~' + ',  ' + six.length + ']]);';

    var pieChartScript3 =
      'var options = {title: ' + '제목' + ',pieHole: 0.4,};' +
      'var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById("donutchart"));' +
      'chart.draw(data, options);}' +
      '</script>';
    console.log(pieChartScript1 + pieChartScript2 + pieChartScript3);
  },
```

I wish to append it in "b.html" file

b.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<!--I wish to append it here-->
<body>

  <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you writing JavaScript inside JavaScript?

Comment: I am currently working with Arcgis webappbuilder  widget, and it uses java script. The reason why I am writing javascript within javascript is because First, I am terrible at coding, second the chart that google provides insert that value in <script> tag.

Comment: If you want to modify `b.html` content from `a.js` means rewrite `b.html` as far as I know, Javascript can't change the file.  I think you can generator `b.html` from `a.js` instead

Comment: _"First, I am terrible at coding"_ that's probably not true. --- Anyway, why not remove the JS inside that string and make it a function?

Comment: Arcgis uses javascript dojo which I am not very familiar with. Only thing I need to do is basically send data that I calculated from a.js to b.html. And to answer your question, yes I could remove the javascript from my string.

Comment: -vietnguyen09 so rather then trying to send data, I should generate html within a.js?  okey I'll try that now, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this js file,you must use in html  file.I have no idea about running the js string as the function you asked.

Comment: strings that I wish to send to b.html is contained in "var pieChartScript1,2,3". createChart() function you see is just a simple function to inserts value that I retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a global var in a.js

```
var myGlobal = "I'm global"
//rest of script
```

in b.html you will be able to use myGlobal, if both are loaded by the browser

Answer (score 0):

Yet again I was being stupid. My goal was to send string data to another html file from js file. i have solved this by using `sessionStorage.setItem()` and `sessionStorage.getItem()`. Pretty good trick to send simple string variable to another file. Thank you for all your help.
Here is more info about this.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score -1):

Use `$('head').append(your string);`
in a.js after you have defined all your strings.

make sure you add Jquery libraries

Note: You should normally add scripts inside body tag and not the head.

Comment: I need to append my string to "b.html" <body> or <head> tag. I am currently searching a way to pass data from a.js to b.html so I can use what you wrote in b.html